# UITableView setEditing Strange animation in iOS7

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When editing a UITableView, I see strange animation.

Here the print screen:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17347115/errorUiTableViewSetEditing.png

When I have a new project with Xcode 4.6.3 (template "Master-Detail Application) and  set the UITableView to Style=Grouped and  Run on a iOS 7 device,  it presents the same problem, if I change to Style=Plain the problem is resolved.

Here the print screen:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17347115/errorTemplateDefault.png

How I can fix this problem for a UITableView with Style=Grouped ?

Thanks,
Hugo

Comment: could you provide more code please?

Comment: `- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    
    if (editing)
    {
        [self.listasComprasTableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {  
        [self.listasComprasTableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    }
}`

Comment: we still need more code: how do you customize your table view's cells? do you change it's frame somehow? which other delegate methods do you implement (like `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`)

Comment: also could you please edit the question? so we have your code formatted.

Comment: and why do you call the parent's setEditing method? i think it's unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the post to most clear explication.

Comment: Please next time you ask a question provide some actual code, not the result it does. By default tableviews don't do such things, so the error is in your code. That's why we'd need to see it. Also if you develop for ios 7, use xcode5. Finally as i mentioned yesterday, i don't think calling "[super setEditing:editing animated:animated];" is necessary.

Comment: The error is in a default template.  Someone can I help me please.

Answer (score 1):

This helped me out with this exact problem:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: What this does is change the behavior of the editing. The default behavior might be broken when compiling with iOS SDK 6.x on a 7.x device.  I'm going to post a radar about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can not set a table to editing and then immediately set it to not editing.  You have to wait for the set to editing animation to finish and then you can set it to not editing.

Comment: Thanks jamihash,I did not explain well my problem, I put the two extracts of code to explain that happens when I am in edit mode and when return to normal mode.

Best I eliminated the second line of code to make this more clear. Thanks,